# Is there someway to determine the current network fee from the bitcoin network/daemon?

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees, network

Is there some way to programmatically extract the current consensus of the transaction fee from the bitcoin network, either by using the daemon or through some other means?

Comment: Check the medium fee of last n blocks? I believe the transaction fee is currently not very variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the medium fee of last n blocks? I believe the transaction fee is currently not very variable. The reference implementation "ensures" that all transactions that are smaller than 1000 bytes, have all outputs over 0,01 BTC and have a large enough priority will be processed, regardless of the transaction fee. Otherwise 0.1 mBTC is paid for every 1000 bytes of transaction (rounded up).

The priority of a transaction can be calculated by [[1]](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees)

```
priority = sum(input_value_in_base_units * input_age) / size_in_bytes
```

Comment: With respect to http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/633/please-post-answers-as-answers-not-as-comments?cb=1, I posted my comment as an answer.